# getline with structure pointer array

Tags: c++, pointers, input, struct

I have to learn memory management in class and how to dynamically allocate memory with the `new` operator.

I have a struct that is

```
struct Course
{
    int courseNumber, creditHours;
    string courseName;
    char grade;
};
```

I am trying to fill the member variables with a for loop but I am unsure how to use a `getline` with `courseName`. I was able to use a regular `cin` but it won't work if the class name has spaces.

Below is my code and what I've tried but I get a arguement error that courseArray is undefined.

```
Course* readCourseArray(int &courses)                           //Read Courses
{
    cout<<"\nHow many courses is the student taking?\n";
    cin>>courses;
    const int *sizePTR = &courses;
    Course *coursePTR = new Course[*sizePTR]; 

    for(int count = 0; count < *sizePTR; count++)  //Enter course information
    {
        cout<<"\nEnter student "<<count+1<<"'s course name\n";
        getline(cin,courseArray[count].courseName);
        cout<<"\nEnter student "<<count+1<<"'s course number\n";
        cin>>coursePTR[count].courseNumber;
        cout<<"\nEnter student "<<count+1<<"'s credit hours\n";
        cin>>coursePTR[count].creditHours;
        cout<<"\nEnter student "<<count+1<<"'s grade\n";
        cin>>coursePTR[count].grade;
    }


    return coursePTR;
}
```

Comment: Ah I'm still a little confused with passing pointers and things and I think I was having problem setting a const int value from a int but I don't remember. It works though.

Comment: If you find that your input gets out of sync, you may discover that you need `std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');` as the last line inside your loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pointer to your array is called `coursePTR`, not `courseArray`. Just replace the name `courseArray` with `coursePTR`.

For this line:

```
const int *sizePTR = &courses;
```

You don't have to do that, you can just use `courses` directly (so, remove all the `*` from the places you use `sizePTR` then change `sizePTR` to `courses`).

Also I hope you are remembering to `delete[]` the return value of `readCourseArray` `:)`

Comment: Derp that is it thanks I was using the name from a different function.